# Unable to publish the dotnet core + angular application

Tags: angular, .net-core, npm-install

I have an application made up of dotnet core + angular(latest version)

It is running when I run this with ng server -o. But during publish(through Visual Studio) I am getting following peer dependency errors

[image]

I tried to run the command npm install **--legacy-peer-deps** but not works.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this.